# Uniform integrability and stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stopping-times, uniform-integrability

I want to know whether there is any example where $X_n$ is uniformly integrable, $N$ is a stopping time and $E[X_N] =\infty$? Or uniform integrability of $X_n$ implies that $E[X_N]< \infty$?

Comment: Is $(X_n)_n$ a $L^1$-martingale?

Comment: @FrankScience Not necessarily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true. Moreover, it seems pretty obvious to me that the fact like this cannot be true without any further assumption like the martingale property; however, the requirement that $N$ should be a stopping time (with respect to the filtration of $X$, I presume) makes it harder to find a counterexample.

Let $\Omega$ be $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure and $X_n(\omega) = \frac{2^n}{n} \mathbf{1}_{(2^{-n},2^{-n+1}]}(\omega)$. Then $$\sup_{n} E[|X_n|\mathbf{1}_{|X_n|>C}] = \sup_{n:\frac{2^n}n>C} \frac1{n} = \frac{1}{\inf\{n: 2^n/n>C\}}\to 0,C\to\infty,$$
so the sequence is uniformly integrable (alternatively, one can use the de la Vallée-Poussin theorem with $V(x) = x\log x$).
However, setting $N = \inf\{n\ge 1: X_n>0\}$, 
$$
E[X_N] = E\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n} \mathbf{1}_{(2^{-n},2^{-n+1}]}(\omega)\right] =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n = +\infty.
$$

Comment: So $$\mathbb E[X_N] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n n^{-1}\mathbb P(X_N = 2^n n^{-1})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n n^{-1} 2^{-n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}  $$ while $$\{N= n\}=\left(2^{-n},\ 2^{-n+1}\right]\in\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n).$$ Very interesting.